# Input tag with password attribute changes mobile site to desktop when focused

Tags: html, css, input, passwords, mobile-chrome

This is a simple form with an input field for the email address and an input field for the password. You can enter your email address without a problem, it keeps its size and does not change except for a small change of input background-color when focused.

[This is the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo3wy.jpg)

The password however, when focused, changes the mobile version of this site to the desktop version. As soon as you focus on something else, say the email, the desktop site will change back to the mobile version. This does not happen on the chrome DevTools. The problem seems to be only on the mobile version of chrome.

[Here you can see that the site changed to the desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzJKL.jpg)

I think that it has something to do with how chrome handles the attribute "password". How do I prevent chrome from changing the mobile site to desktop and back, just because of the password?

**HTML**

```
<form class="loginform" action="includes/login.inc.php" method="POST">
        <h1>Log-in</h1>
        <label for="userEmail">Email</label><br>
        <input name="userEmail" autocomplete="username" type="text" placeholder="Email"><br>
        <label for="userPwd">Wachtwoord</label><br>
        <input name="userPwd" type="password" autocomplete="current-password" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
        <br>
        <input name="onthoudtmij" type="checkbox"><label for="onthoudtmij" style="display: inline-block;">Onthoudt mij</label>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log-in">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>Nog geen account? <a href="registreren.php">klik hier!</a></h1>
        <br>
        <a href="reset-wachtwoord.php">Wachtwoord vergeten? klik hier!</a>
    </form>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) and (orientation: portrait)
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email], input[type=tel] {
   width: auto;
}
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email], input[type=tel] {
   width: 50%;
   padding: 12px 20px;
   margin: 8px 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #256578;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) and (orientation: portrait)
p, li, h4, td, label, input, textarea {
   font-size: 4.5vw;
   padding: 0;
}
input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus, input[type=email]:focus, input[type=tel]:focus {
   background-color: #c4c4c4;
}
```